# attributeError: 'list' object has no attribute.....

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

I am getting attributeError, but I don't understand....

```
class User():

    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.login_attempt = 0

class Admin(User):

    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        super().__init__(first, last, age)
        self.privilages = Privilages()


class Privilages():

    def __init__(self, privilages = ''):
        self.privilages = []

    def show_privilages(self):
        print("There are the privilages... : ")
        if self.privilages:
            for privilage in self.privilages:
                print("- " + privilage)
        else:
             print("The user has no privilages. ")


sarah.privilages = ['can add post', 'can delete post']
sarah.privilages.show_privilages()
```

I am not sure what I am missing here, I used for loops to go over the list and print it out, however I keep getting error of "'list' object has no attribute 'show_privileges'"

Comment: You do `sarah.privilages = []` on the line above. `sarah.privilages` is then a list. What is your intent? Did you mean `sarah.privilages.privilages = [...]`?

Comment: Not the cause of your error, but "privilege" is spelled with an "e".

Comment: Oops! I haven't much paid attention on spelling. Anyway, I did `sarah.privilages = []` because I wanted to put values in `self.privilages = []`. Can you explain why it's `sarah.privilages.privilages = []`?

Comment: @Sarah Because you start with the Admin class object, then you access it's attribute 'privileges' which is the Privileges class, and then from within that class you access show_privileges

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning a list to `sarah.privilages`, so it surely does not have a `show_privilages` method. You should make the `__init__` method of `Admin` take a list of privileges as a parameter, so it can pass on to the `__init__` method of `Privilages` to initialize its `privilages` attribute:

```
class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, privilages):
        super().__init__(first, last, age)
        self.privilages = Privilages(privilages)


class Privilages():
    def __init__(self, privilages):
        self.privilages = privilages

    def show_privilages(self):
        print("There are the privilages... : ")
        if self.privilages:
            for privilage in self.privilages:
                print("- " + privilage)
        else:
             print("The user has no privilages. ")

sarah = Admin('sarah','mary','smith', ['can add post', 'can delete post'])
sarah.privilages.show_privilages()
```

This outputs:

```
There are the privilages... : 
- can add post
- can delete post
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a separate Privileges class. The class should have one
attribute, privileges, that stores a list of strings.
Move the show_privileges() method to this class. Make a Privileges instance
as an attribute in the Admin class. Create a new instance of Admin and use your
method to show its privileges

```
class User():
    """Represent a simple user profile."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        """Initialize the user."""
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.location = location.title()

    class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, username, email, location)
        #Initialize an empty set of privileges.
        self.privileges= Privileges()

class Privileges():
    def __init__(self,privileges =[]):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def Show_privileges(self):
        print("\nPrivileges: ")
        if self.privileges:
            for privilege in self.privileges:
                print("- " + str(privilege))
        else:
            print("- this user has no privileges.")

        eric = Admin('suraj', 'boi', 'e_mater', 'e_matthes100@example.com', 'alaska')
    eric.describe_user()
    
    eric.privileges.Show_privileges()
    print("\nAdding privileges...")
    eric_privileges = [
        'can reset passwords',
        'can moderate discussions',
        'can suspend accounts',
        ]
    
    eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges
    eric.privileges.Show_privileges()
```